# How to draw line chart for male and female of each county?

Tags: dataframe, plot, julia, statsplots

Dataframe, as follows:

```
julia> df6
135×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ County      │ Year  │ Female │ Male   │
│     │ String      │ Int64 │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼─────────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ Asotin      │ 2008  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 2   │ Asotin      │ 2009  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 3   │ Asotin      │ 2010  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 4   │ Asotin      │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 5   │ Asotin      │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 6   │ Benton      │ 2008  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 7   │ Benton      │ 2009  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 8   │ Benton      │ 2010  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 9   │ Benton      │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 10  │ Benton      │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 11  │ Chelan      │ 2008  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 12  │ Chelan      │ 2009  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 13  │ Chelan      │ 2010  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 14  │ Chelan      │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 15  │ Chelan      │ 2012  │ 0      │ 2      │
│ 16  │ Clallam     │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 17  │ Clallam     │ 2009  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 18  │ Clallam     │ 2010  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 19  │ Clallam     │ 2011  │ 1      │ 1      │
│ 20  │ Clallam     │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 21  │ Clark       │ 2008  │ 0      │ 1      │
⋮
│ 114 │ Thurston    │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 115 │ Thurston    │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 116 │ Walla Walla │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 117 │ Walla Walla │ 2009  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 118 │ Walla Walla │ 2010  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 119 │ Walla Walla │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 120 │ Walla Walla │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 121 │ Whatcom     │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 122 │ Whatcom     │ 2009  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 123 │ Whatcom     │ 2010  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 124 │ Whatcom     │ 2011  │ 1      │ 1      │
│ 125 │ Whatcom     │ 2012  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 126 │ Whitman     │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 127 │ Whitman     │ 2009  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 128 │ Whitman     │ 2010  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 129 │ Whitman     │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 130 │ Whitman     │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 131 │ Yakima      │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 132 │ Yakima      │ 2009  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 133 │ Yakima      │ 2010  │ 1      │ 2      │
│ 134 │ Yakima      │ 2011  │ 0      │ 3      │
│ 135 │ Yakima      │ 2012  │ 0      │ 1      │
```

The following code draws line chart for male and female of King County:

```
line_chart = @pipe df6|>
                   filter(row -> row[:County] == ("King"), _) |>
                   plot(_.Year, [_.Male, _.Female],
                        title = "King County Youth Suicides",
                        label=["Male" "Female"],
                        xlabel="Year",
                        ylabel="Suicides",
                        size=(700,700)
                        )
```

Grouped Data:

```
julia> grouped_data = @pipe df6|>
                          groupby(_, :County)
GroupedDataFrame with 27 groups based on key: County
First Group (5 rows): County = "Asotin"
│ Row │ County │ Year  │ Female │ Male   │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ Asotin │ 2008  │ 1      │ 0      │
│ 2   │ Asotin │ 2009  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 3   │ Asotin │ 2010  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 4   │ Asotin │ 2011  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 5   │ Asotin │ 2012  │ 0      │ 0      │
⋮
Last Group (5 rows): County = "Yakima"
│ Row │ County │ Year  │ Female │ Male   │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ Yakima │ 2008  │ 0      │ 0      │
│ 2   │ Yakima │ 2009  │ 0      │ 1      │
│ 3   │ Yakima │ 2010  │ 1      │ 2      │
│ 4   │ Yakima │ 2011  │ 0      │ 3      │
│ 5   │ Yakima │ 2012  │ 0      │ 1      │
```

While trying to draw line chart for male suicides and females suicides of each County, throws the following error:

```
julia> line_chart = @pipe df6|>
                          groupby(_, :County) |>
                          plot(_.Year, [_.Male, _.Female],
                               title = "King County Youth Suicides",
                               label=["Male" "Female"],
                               xlabel="Year",
                               ylabel="Suicides",
                               size=(700,700)
                               )
ERROR: type GroupedDataFrame has no field Year
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::GroupedDataFrame{DataFrame}, ::Symbol) at ./Base.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[27]:1
```

**Update 1:**

The following code draws line charts for male and female suicides of each county:

```
counties = unique(df6.County)

line_chart=plot(lw =3, 
                title = "Youth Suicides",
                xlabel="Year",
                ylabel="Suicides",
                size=(1200,1000)
)
for county in counties
                   @pipe df6|>
                   filter(row -> row[:County] == county, _) |>
                   plot!(line_chart, _.Year, [_.Male, _.Female],
                        label=["$county Male" "$county Female"],
                        )
println("County : $county")
end
savefig(line_chart, "line_chart.pdf")
```

Please guide me in drawing line charts correctly and efficiently for male and female suicides of each County?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does not use piping (it could be piped too).

Group and add Male and Female in each group:

```
gdf6 = combine(groupby(df6, [:County, :Year]), :Male => sum, :Female => sum)
```

Use [StatsPlots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl):

```
@df gdf plot(:Year, :Male_sum, group={County_Male=:County})

@df gdf plot!(:Year, :Female_sum, group={County_Female=:County})
```

Another option would be to stack the dataframe before plotting and then you can use a single plot command:

```
sdf6 = stack(gdf6, [:Male_sum, :Female_sum])

@df sdf6 plot(:Year, :value, group=(county=:County, sex=:variable))
```

If you want a bar plot then change `plot` with `groupedbar`, which might be better visually.

Comment: Hi I need male suicides line and female suicides line for each county without summing up ie. 27x2=54 lines

Comment: Since you have a single value for each country in each year, you can just skip the first step. You should be able to just stack the dataframe and use StatsPlots to plot with the @df macro.